# Calling Matlab Compiler from inside C# app throws exception

Tags: c#, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I found this code to invoke the Matlab compiler, it works fine when the function is called from Matlab command prompt, I build this function to .Net Assembly but whenever I try to use it in my C# app in order to build some .m file I get an exception, where do you think my problem is?

Matlab Code:

```
function compileCode(mfile,dllName , dnetdir)

    %% Create directories if needed
    if (exist(dnetdir, 'dir') ~= 7)
        mkdir(dnetdir);
    end

    %% Build .NET Assembly
    eval(['mcc -N -d ''' dnetdir ''' -W ''dotnet:' dllName ',' ...
          '' dllName ',0.0,private'' -T link:lib ''' mfile '''']);
    end
```

C# code:

```
var cmm = new compiler.MatlabCompiler();
MWCharArray x = new MWCharArray(@"C:\Users\ePezhman\Documents\MATLAB\Graph2D.m");
MWCharArray y = new MWCharArray("Graph");
MWCharArray z = new MWCharArray(@"C:\Matlab\dotnet");
cmm.compileCode(x,y,z);
```

Exception:

> ... MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error ...  Undefined function 'mcc' for
>   input arguments of type 'char'. Error in => compileCode.m at line 9.
>
> ... Matlab M-code Stack Trace ...
>       at file C:\Users\ePezhman\AppData\Local\Temp\ePezhman\mcrCache8.0\compil0\compiler\compileCode.m,
>   name compileCode, line 9.

Comment: It would be much easier to invoke the command directly from C#. Using `Process.Start()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, I assume you are trying to compile a function that can dynamically compile other functions..

Unfortunately, I dont think the `mcc` function can be compiled/deployed itself

---

To be exact, the problem you are seeing is because MATLAB needs to know all functions called at compile-time, and by using `eval`, it wont figure it out on its own (since it wont parse inside the string). You can fix this particular issue by writing [special comments](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/function.html) for the compiler..

```
function myEval()
    %#function foo
    eval('...');
end
```

(Another alternative is using [function handles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7409779/97160)).

Still even if you do that, it will fail at runtime inside the `mcc` function saying that: `"License checkout failed, [...] Cannot find a valid license for Compiler"`.

The reason is as mentioned in the comments, `mcc` is a development tool and cannot be deployed to standalone programs which only depends on the free MCR runtime.

Think about it, if it was possible, it would defeat the whole purpose of buying licenses for the product, as you could create a standalone program that can compiler other codes without having the Compiler toolbox :)

Comment: There's no mention of deployment. The question is purely technical. This is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @DavidHefernan: MATLAB Compiler (Builder NE) is a product used to generate .NET assemblies from MATLAB code, which can then be used from C#. `mcc` is the command used to compile the code. So it is pertaining to deployment of MATLAB code (which is an interpreted language by the way)

Comment: Yes, I know. The question is why the code fails. Not whether or not `mcc` can be redistributed.

Comment: because `mcc` function cannot be compiled itself. There is also a list of other functions that cannot be compiled.

Comment: OK, I think I understand. I think your answer is not terribly clear. However, the answer is as I said in my comment. Call `mcc` from C# directly. I think you could usefully add that to the answer.

Comment: Remember that `mcc` is a development tool (it is in fact implemented using a internal MEX-file), and that the compiled code only depends on the MCR runtime, and doesnt need to have MATLAB installed on the target machine.. So invoking it as a process from C# does not apply as well

Comment: Surely you can invoke `matlab.exe` passing the `mcc` command string and call that from `Process.Start()`. And you can issue mcc commands from the command line too, according to the docs I can see.

Comment: @DavidHefernan: But then you assume MATLAB itself is installed, which isnt necessarily true. The generated .NET assembly can be used **without** having MATLAB on the target machine, it only needs the freely available [MCR runtime](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/)... You see the most common use of MALTAB Compiler products is generate standalone programs/libraries that can be used by customers who dont have MATLAB itself.

Comment: That's back to my original point. We don't know whether or not ePezhman wants to do that. Perhaps this program is only for her personal use on a machine that has MATLAB installed. On the other hand, if she is trying to distribute a MATLAB compiler, then quite clearly, as you say, it won't work.